# how to do Gremlin contain search for both number and string

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Neptune 1.0.2.1 +  Gremlin + nodejs.

I have a vertext and  property, e.g. Vertex - Device, property -  Test, the Test property could store different type of data, e.g. number and string

Vertex 1 - Test = ['ABCD','xyz']
Vertex 2 - Test = [123,'XYZ']

I want to do a 'containing' search, e.g. Test=A, or Test=123 regardless the datatype.

I was trying

```
queryText = 'BC' //this throw error
or queryText = 123 //this actually works
//I expect both case should hit the result.

g.V().hasLabel('Device').or(__.has('Test', parseFloat(queryText)), __.has('Test', textP.containing(queryText)));
```

but get 'InternalFailureException\' error

Is it possible I can write a single query regardless the datatype?

if not possible, or at least make textP.containing work with multiple query assuming I know the datatype? right now the containing search throw error if the property contains number

Comment: Which version of the Neptune Engine are you using? I was not able to reproduce the error you saw so far.  This worked for me with one of my grapgs.  gremlin> g.V('3').or(has('city',TextP.containing('sti')),has('city',123))

Comment: See answer I think you have a bracket in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the closing bracket in the wrong place inside the or() step. You need to close the first has step before the comma.

In your example

```
g.V().hasLabel('Device').or(__.has('Test', parseFloat(queryText), __.has('Test', textP.containing(queryText))));
```

Which should be

```
g.V().hasLabel('Device').or(__.has('Test', parseFloat(queryText)), __.has('Test', textP.containing(queryText)));
```

EDITED and UPDATED

With the corrected query and additional clarification about the data model containing different types for the same property key, I was able to reproduce what you are seeing. However, the same behavior can be seen using TinkerGraph as well as Neptune. The error message generated is  is a little different but the meaning is the same. Given the fact that TinkerGraph behaves the same way I am of the opinion that Neptune is behaving consistently with the "reference" implementation. That said, this raises a question as to whether the TextP predicates should be smarter and check the type of the property before attempting the test.

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('x',12.5)
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('x','ABCDEF')
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test').or(has('x',12.3),has('x',TextP.containing('CDE')))
java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

ADDITIONAL UPDATE

I created a Jira issue so the Apache TinkerPop community can consider making a change to the TextP predicates.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2375

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, the bracket was not the problem, I think the issue is if I have multiple values in a property, e.g. for vertex 1, Test=[22,'string1','string2'], for vertext 2, Test=['string0','string1'], then I got UnsupportedOperationException\ error

Comment: I am on Neptune 1.0.2.1

Comment: try search by string, and have multiple data type in single v property, if you could reproduce the error

Comment: ok, i did more testing, i think it has nothing to do with multiple value in single property, as long as I have different data type for a property, the textP.containing throws error

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. I will look into this some more using the configuration you describe. Do you see the same error if you run the query from the Gremlin Console?

Comment: yes, the console throws same error UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: The latest version of Neptune seems to have a better error message. I can also reproduce this behavior using TinkerGraph. The only time there is no exception is if the number is matched exactly before being tested as a String. In general overloading the type of a property is something that should probably be discouraged.